# FlexBoxLayout align-self:flex-end not working in nativescript-vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, flexbox, nativescript

in my nativescript-vue app I'm using flex layout to create a custom ActionBar component to reuse, I'm trying to ge the search icon to align to end of row, this shuld be easy using align-self:flex-end but it's not working for me, honestly I'm new to nativescript and the whole layouting thing acts wonky as hell...

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQgWk.png

This is my code:

```
<FlexboxLayout style="width:100%; height:auto; flex-direction:column; align-items:flex-start; justify-content:center;">
        <FlexboxLayout style="width:100%; height:85px; padding:0px 10px; background-color:blue;  flex-direction:row; justify-content:flex-start; align-items:center;">
            <Label :text="'fa-bars' | fonticon" class="fa c_light" style="font-size:25; margin:0 10;"/>
            <Label text="Pacome" fontSize="24" class="c_light" style="margin:0 10;"/>
            <!--THIS SHOULD BE ALIGNED TO THE RIGHT-->
            <Label :text="'fa-search' | fonticon" class="fa c_light" style="font-size:25; margin:0 10; align-self:flex-end;"/>
        </FlexboxLayout >
    </FlexboxLayout >
```

Comment: `align-self` works on the cross axis not on the same axis. So you can not put icon at the end with `align-self` set to `flex-end` here. You could use a GridLayout to simply split the space.

Comment: I don't understand this, in web flexbox it works for me, and since I set flex direction to row all my child items are in the x-axis right?

Comment: Yes. But align self will work on cross axis then - y axis. The concept is same on web too.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and this fixed it.
Add the order property to the children: `order=0` and `order=1`.